# UiPath Studio Activity Query

Tags: uipath, uipath-robot

I just need to know what is the entry point of a process or a library when we create and run them in UiPath Studio

For Example When we create a angularjs Program we know when we run it the entry point of that application is "ng-app"

UiPath Studio Version - 2021.10.5
License - Community License

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry point of the process (the main workflow) is defined in project.json of your process. For example :

```
{
  "name": "MyTask",
  "description": "MyTask",
  "main": "Main.xaml", <--- This is your entry point workflow
  "dependencies": {
    "UiPath.Database.Activities": "[1.4.0]",
    "UiPath.Excel.Activities": "[2.9.5]",
    "UiPath.Mail.Activities": "[1.9.5]",
    "UiPath.System.Activities": "[20.10.3]",
    "UiPath.UIAutomation.Activities": "[20.10.8]"
  }
  ...
```